# What is the best way to handle delimited text(jsp/java)

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I am setting some values in my jsp with '/' delimiter. The value looks like

```
<input id="newSourceDealerInput" type="hidden" value="New/<key>/<dealer>/active" name="newSourceDealerInput">
```

The dealer is a string and contain '/', for that matter any special character. I need to separate the values in the java(which I am doing by split("/") method.

How should I handle the case where dealer has "/" character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [java.text.MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/?java/text/MessageFormat.html) class:

```
String pattern="New/{0}/{1}/active";
MessageFormat mf=new MessageFormat(pattern);

Object[] values= mf.parse("New/key/dealer/active");
> results in ["key", "dealer"]      


values= mf.parse("New/key/dea/ler/active");
> results in ["key", "dea/ler"]
```

This pattern will only work if the '<key>' element present no slashes.

**EDIT** - As the begining and trailing parts of the string are also variables, you should consider using a Regular Expression, and evaluate the value using the [java.util.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) classes:

```
    String source="Old/0123340key/d/ea/le-r/busy";

    //define two alphanumeric slash-delimited blocks, 
    //followed by a named capturing group (named 'dealer')
    //and a traling alphanumeric group beginning with a slash
    String regex="(^([a-zA-Z0-9])*\\/([a-zA-Z0-9])*\\/)(?<dealer>.+)(\\/([a-zA-Z0-9])*$)";

    Pattern pat=Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher match=pat.matcher(source);
    String result="";
    if(match.matches()) {       
       result = match.group("dealer");
               //> returns "d/ea/le-r"
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "if the element present no slashes"? In your second example `dea/ler` has a slash?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the '<key>' element. Editing. Thanks for pointing!

Comment: 'New' and 'active' is also not fixed here. There can be different value(but not containing '/'). How do I set me pattern now? "{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}, wont work I think for the 2nd example

Comment: @user2353827 then youi should consider using Pattern and Matcher classes combined. Please, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I dont have java 7 in the production, so I cant use the solution. But I came up with other solution

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    String source="Old/0123340/d/e/a-ler/busy";
    int pos1=nthOccurrence(source,'/',2);
    int pos2=nthOccurrenceFromLast(source,'/',1);
    System.out.println(source.substring(pos1+1, pos2)); 
        //gives output d/e/a-ler

    }


 public static int nthOccurrence(String str, char c, int n) {
     int pos = str.indexOf(c, 0);
     while (--n > 0 && pos != -1)
         pos = str.indexOf(c, pos+1);
     return pos;
 }

 public static int nthOccurrenceFromLast(String str, char c, int n) {
     int pos = str.lastIndexOf(c, str.length());
     while (--n > 0 && pos != -1)
         pos = str.lastIndexOf(c, pos-1);
     return pos;
 }
```